# Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, fedora

I want to install in my Fedora 12 based planet lab nodes one OMF RC:
It requres ruby 1.9.3. So, I installed git, then ruby-devel then rvm. With rvm i installed:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

After all this when i want to install:

```
gem install omf_rc --pre --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

It gives me the following error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> > ERROR:  Error installing omf_rc:
> >
> > > ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> #### /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>
> checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers

Please let me know how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you need to install libxml, try:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Comment: Hi Said, You really saved my day. Thanks a lot. It worked after I used your command.

Comment: then you can check it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Also it needs the following installation:

```
sudo yum install -y git make gcc-c++
```

and

```
sudo yum groupinstall development-tools development-libs
```

Comment: Also sudo yum install libyaml